# Rails has_many associations are not saved when only attributes are changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two models, `Profile` and `Skill`, where a profile `has_many` skills.

I am using Rails as an API and passing an array of skill objects.

I'm doing `@profile.skills = @skills` in the controller, where `@skills` is my data from the frontend.

Whenever I *delete* or *add a new* skill, the above works as expected - also, `@profile.skills.replace(@skills)` works just the same.

The associated object gets deleted or created in the database as well. All as expected.

However, if I only *change* one or more attributes on an already existing skill, the changes are not saved to the database.

If I log `@profile.skills` *after* the above line of code, it seems like the changes expected are present.

But it does not get saved to the database and on the next request the changes are obviously not present.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show us your implementation of profile and skills?

Comment: Need to see more of your code, but are you calling the `save` method?

Comment: You need to add a reproducible example of what you're doing to your question, plus the log of any interaction with the server and/or the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass like this:

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skills 

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills 
end
```

or

```rb
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skills, autosave: true
end
```

after that, edit the same attribute of the same record and save

```rb
@profile.skills.same.same_attr = new_val
@profile.save
```

accepts_nested_attributes_for - it also adds autosave to asociations, and a lot of other things, you can see more in the documentation and source code
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

a little bit about how autosave works for associations
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html